Type a Listener Function for Discriminated Unions in TypeScript
I have a discriminated union of shapes:
type Circle = { type: 'circle'; radius: number };
type Square = { type: 'square'; x: number };
type Rectangle = { type: 'rectangle'; x: number; y: number };
type Shape = Circle | Square | Rectangle;

I'd like to have listeners that are called when a shape is detected. The addListener function should have shape type and a callback as arguments:
type Listener<Type extends Shape> = {
  type: Type['type'];
  callback: (detected: Type) => void;
};

const listeners: Listener<Shape>[] = [];

function addListener<Type extends Shape>(type: Type['type'], callback: (detected: Type) => void) {
  listeners.push({ type, callback }); // Error: Type '(detected: Type) => void' is not assignable to type '(detected: Shape) => void'.
}

Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't allow me to add the listener to the array: Error: Type '(detected: Type) => void' is not assignable to type '(detected: Shape) => void'.
Is there any way of convincing TypeScript to allow this and maintain type information for the callback argument?
TypeScript Playground link

See Function Parameter Bivariance in the TS Handbook. If that information answers your question, I can write an answer explaining (or find a duplicate target question)… if not, what am I missing?

This is more or less the same problem as in ms/TS#30581, but I can't seem to successfully perform the "standard" refactoring to generics as shown in ms/TS#47109. Having a single array that you filter doesn't work very well in the type system; it's easier to have an object full of arrays, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
